# c# Как продолжить скачивание после обрыва соединения с интернетом

Tags: c#

Скачиваю файл, но после как интернет снова в бою, он не продолжает загрузку 
Как исправить?

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.DownloadFileAsync(Uri, Path, DWMVC);
```

P.S: Нужно чтобы при отключения интернет соединения,останавливалась загрузка файл, а после возобновления интернета,снова качала оставшие файлы!

Comment: Весь UI-код в вашем вопросе лишний, имеет смысл убрать его. Чем меньше кода, тем больше вероятность получить хороший ответ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

На основе кода из ответа @AkaInq (добавил `using` и проверку кода возврата):

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
var fi = new FileInfo(path);
var havePart = fi.Exists;
if (havePart)
    request.AddRange(fi.Length);
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    var partialDownload = havePart && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
    using (var file = File.Open(path, partialDownload ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
    using (var net = response.GetResponseStream())
        net.CopyTo(file);
}
```

Добавьте try/catch в нужном месте по вкусу.

Answer (score 3):

вот как-то так, правда это не через webclient:

```csharp
static void DownloadFile(string sSourceURL, string sDestinationPath)
{
    long iFileSize = 0;
    int iBufferSize = 1024;
    iBufferSize *= 1000;
    long iExistLen = 0;
    System.IO.FileStream saveFileStream;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(sDestinationPath))
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo fINfo = 
           new System.IO.FileInfo(sDestinationPath);
        iExistLen = fINfo.Length;
    }
    if (iExistLen > 0)
        saveFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(sDestinationPath, 
          System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, 
          System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
    else
        saveFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(sDestinationPath, 
          System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, 
          System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);

    System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwRq;
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse hwRes;
    hwRq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(sSourceURL);
    hwRq.AddRange((int)iExistLen);
    System.IO.Stream smRespStream;
    hwRes = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)hwRq.GetResponse();
    smRespStream = hwRes.GetResponseStream();

    iFileSize = hwRes.ContentLength;

    int iByteSize;
    byte[] downBuffer = new byte[iBufferSize];

    while ((iByteSize = smRespStream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему не просто через `Stream.CopyTo`? И вы забыли закрыть потоки, так что будет потеря данных.

Comment: А ещё вы должны посмотреть на возвращаемый код: 200 или 206. И в зависимости от этого затирать или нет начало скачанного файла.

Comment: Что-то слишком большой кусок кода, а чем Webclient хуже?

Comment: @TriX HttpWebRequest.AddRange