# C# WebClient, заголовки, Range

Tags: c#, загрузка, httpwebrequest

Всем привет.
Каким образом можно реализовать дозагрузку файлов с помощью класса WebClient?
Пробовал устанавливать заголовок:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Range, "bytes=-" + file.Length.ToString());
```

Таким образом я у существующего, но не до конца загруженного файла, беру его размер и подставляю в заголовок "Range", чтобы загрузка началась с этого размера и до конца.
Но загрузка вообще не начинается.
Можно такое реализовать через WebClient? 
Если нет, то каким образом это можно сделать через httpwebrequest, если уже код написан под WebClient?

Comment: *"Но загрузка вообще не начинается"* - а что происходит?

Comment: Ничего.
http://paste2.org/x1UUnxV8
Просто не начинает загружать и выводит:
"Downloading..."

Comment: Не вижу обработку ошибок.

Comment: Вы вызываете асинхронную операцию - и должны отслеживать не только ее успешное выполнение, но и неуспешное.

Comment: Здорово.
А как должна выглядеть в данном случае обработка ошибок?

Comment: Как минимум, событие DownloadFileCompleted.

Comment: System.Net.WebException: Исключение во время запроса WebClient. ---> System.ArgumentException: Заголовок "Range" необходимо изменить с помощью соответствующего свойства или метода.
Имя параметра: name
   в System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ThrowOnRestrictedHeader(String headerName)
   в System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Add(String name, String value)
   в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_Headers(WebHeaderCollection value)
   в System.Net.WebClient.CopyHeadersTo(WebRequest request)
   в System.Net.WebClie

Comment: Ну вот. Вам уже все рассказали :)

Comment: Вот еще из доков: *"Класс HttpWebRequest имеет свойства для установки некоторых заголовков, перечисленных выше.Если для приложения необходима установка этих заголовков, то класс HttpWebRequest класса следует использовать вместо класса WebRequest."*

Comment: Вообще-то, нет. Вопрос в шапке заключается совершенно в другом.

"Можно такое реализовать через WebClient? Если нет, то каким образом это можно сделать через httpwebrequest, если уже код написан под WebClient?"

Может ошибка мне и дала ответ на первый вопрос, но их два. 
Так или иначе, не понятно, можно ли вообще дозагрузить файл в уже существующий, чтобы он еще и не перезаписался.

Comment: Рекомендуется использовать HttpClient вместо WebClient. HttpClient - быстрее, многопоточнее и типизированнее.

Comment: @Serj-Tm, мне не нужна многопоточность. Достаточно загрузки файла, возможности докачки без переписи файла, а добавлением докачиваемого содержимого в него и наличие колбеков с завершением загрузки файла и прогрессом.

Comment: Дубликат? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/531993/10105

Comment: Стараюсь использовать это: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/97872

Answer (score 3):

Заголовок `Range` нельзя установить явно через коллекцию `Headers`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx.

Когда вы начнете скачивать файл, у вас возникнет исключение `WebException` с сообщением

> The 'Range' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method

Однако, вы можете создать наследника `WebClient`, исправив в нем эту оплошность. Думаю, что заменить везде использование `WebClient` на `MyWebClient` не составит труда:

```
class MyWebClient: WebClient
{
    private int _position;

    // установка позиции, откуда будет возобновлено скачивание
    public void SetFromPosition(int position)
    {
        _position = position;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
       var request = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(address);

       // если позиция задана, установим заголовок range легальным способом
       if (_position > 0)
           request.AddRange(_position);

       return request;
   }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
var client = new MyWebClient();

var info = new FileInfo(file);
if (info.Exists) {
    client.SetFromPosition((int)info.Length);
}

client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), file);

// ...
```

---

Метод для докачки файла:

```
public new void DownloadFile(Uri url, string file)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)) {
        using (var response = OpenRead(url)) {
            response.CopyTo(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Пример дозагрузки во временный файл с последующим слиянием файлов:

```
var client = new MyWebClient();
string tmpFile = file + ".bak"; // временный файл

c.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, args) => {
    // дозапись из src в dest
    using (var dest = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)) {
        using (var src = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
            src.CopyTo(dest);
        }
    }

    File.Delete(tmpFile);
};

var info = new FileInfo(file);
if (info.Exists) {
    client.SetFromPosition((int)info.Length);
}

c.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), tmpFile);
```

Comment: Щикаарно. 
Вот только в результате получилось то, что я и ожидал - файл перезаписывается. 
Но закачка с нужного фрагмента работает.

Comment: @kompas да, посмотрел в исходники, DownloadFile действительно создает файлстрим с опцией FileMode.Create. Тогда придется еще писать свой метод DownloadFile.

Comment: Либо сохранять в какой-то другой файл, а потом их склеивать

Comment: @kvm, это можно, да. В принципе, подойдет и докачка в файл .bak, но каким образом склеить их потом?

Comment: @kompas, у WebClient есть метод OpenRead, который дает доступ к стриму, дописал пример, как можно докачать файл без перезаписи.

Comment: @kvm, добавил, но все равно перезаписывалось. Видимо, потому что я использую метод DownloadFileAsync.
Изменил код на такой:
http://paste2.org/YMxyFnk3
Но теперь не работают колбеки. Статус загрузки не отображает, но докачка работает.

Comment: @kompas асинхронное скачивание - это уже отдельный вопрос, довольно сложный. Тогда лучше сделайте склейку файлов, точно так же, как скачивание, только открываете два FileStream, один на чтение (второй кусок файла), другой на дополнение (первый кусок) и копируйте первый стрим во второй через CopyTo

Comment: @kvm, так или иначе, спасибо, буду пытаться реализовать асинхронно с Вашими примерами выше :)

Comment: @kvm, а не подскажите пример с написанным Вами MyWebClient и копированием докаченного файла?